# Fetch images sent to your Telegram Bot using Django

Tags: python, django, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to fetch image sent by the user to the telegram-bot.
And save this image in the database, just want to see this image in the URL/admin.
My models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BotUser(models.Model):
    chat_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    step = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    fio = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    city = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    date_wedding = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    date_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'user_id = ' + str(self.id) + ' chat_id = ' + str(self.chat_id) + ' ' + self.fio + ' ' + self.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Telegram User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Telegram User'
```

And my views.py
`import telebot` and then

```
mes = 'Hello!'
bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)

mes = 'What is your name?'
bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)
user.step = 'input_name'
user.save()

return HttpResponse('OK')

if user.step == 'input_name':
    user.name = text

    mes = 'What is your city?'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)

    user.step = 'input_city'
    user.save()

    return HttpResponse('OK')

if user.step == 'input_city':
    user.city = text

    mes = 'What is your birthday YYYY-MM-DD.'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)

    user.step = 'input_date'
    user.save()

    return HttpResponse('OK')

if user.step == 'input_date':
    user.date_wedding = text

    mes = 'What is your photo?'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)

    user.step = 'input_photo'
    user.save()

    return HttpResponse('OK')

if user.step == 'input_photo':
    updates = bot.get_updates()
    user.photo = ([u.message.photo for u in updates if u.message.photo])

    # user.photo = file_id
    user.save()

    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

And I get error look like local variable 'chat_id' referenced before assignment.
And I think error in user.step == 'input_date'.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You have not assigned any value to ``chat_id`` before calling ``bot.send_message``

Comment: @pa-wa, sorry, on which line are you talking about?
I can't see this line.

Comment: 2nd line of ``views.py`` for example. Where is the value of ``chat_id`` being set ?